# How can I prevent the post_modified column in wp_posts from being updated?

Tags: post-meta, date

On my site, I display each post's Last Updated date instead of its Published date in order to let visitors know how recent the post is.

I'm currently developing a new theme, and some of the features I'm building will require me to make edits to almost every post's featured image and custom fields.

I'd like to prevent the Last Updated date from being changed when I do these updates, as I'm not really updating the content.

Any way to do this? My current idea is to simply change the names of the post_modified and post_modified_gmt while I do the update - will this break anything, since WordPress will be trying to update columns that technically don't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to `functions.php` when you are meddling and remove it after, or comment it out:

```
function no_mod_wpse_136092($data,$postarr){
  if (empty($postarr['ID'])) return $data;
  $old = get_post($postarr['ID']);
  if (!empty($old)) {
    $data['post_modified'] = $old->post_modified;
    $data['post_modified_gmt'] = $old->post_modified_gmt;
  }
  return $data;
}
add_action('wp_insert_post_data','no_mod_wpse_136092',10,2);
```